# Kubernetes Cronjob: Reset missed start times after cluster recovery

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob, k8s-cronjobber

I have a cluster that includes a Cronjob scheduled to run every 5 minutes.

We recently experienced an issue that incurred downtime and required manual recovery of the cluster. Although now healthy again, this particular cronjob is failing to run with the following error:

```
Cannot determine if job needs to be started: Too many missed start time (> 100). Set or decrease .spec.startingDeadlineSeconds or check clock skew.
```

I understand that the Cronjob has 'missed' a number of scheduled jobs while the cluster was down, and this has past a threshold at which no further jobs will be scheduled.

How can I reset the number of missed start times and have these jobs scheduled again (without scheduling **all** the missed jobs to suddenly run?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the [kubernetes Cronjob docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/), there does not seem to be a way to cleanly resolve this. Setting the `.spec.startingDeadlineSeconds` value to a large number will re-schedule **all** missed occurrences that fall within the increased window.

My solution was just to `kubectl delete cronjob x-y-z` and recreate it, which worked as desired.

Comment: It's actually, you need to decrease it / set it to a really low value for it to reschedule the cronjob